# How to filter an array inside an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, mutation

I'm struggling to filter an **array** inside an **object** on a condition (in my case filter if value1 <> value2 **and** toggle is true)

```
myObject = { 
    value: 1, 
    capacitiesArray: [{value1: 10, value2: 10}, {value1: 10, value2: 20}] 
}
```

so my output should be

```
filtredObject = { 
    value: 1, 
    capacitiesArray: [{value1: 10, value2: 20}] 
}
```

I created this function called "filterObject", that have in parameter "myObject" et "toggle"(if toggle true then filer "capacitiesArray" else don't filter "capacitiesArray"

I tried to do it by doing that, but it's doesn't seem to work :(

I think I'm having an issue with object mutation

```
function filterObject(myObject: MyObject, toggle: boolean): MyObject {
if(toggle) {
  const rows = myObject.capacitiesArray; 
  const capacitiesArray = rows.filter((row) => row.value1 !== row.value2); 
  myObject.capacitiesArray = capacitiesArray; 
  return myObject; 
  } 
return myObject; 
}
```

Here's a link for the code to unit test the function https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-test-run-draft-gczdsg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

in app.component.spec.ts

the second **test** "filterRowOnCosCoeValue should filter operationalCapacities when **toggle on**" **passes** (that's fine, since the expected result is "**expectedOperationalNoticeMock**")

but it **should not pass** when I provide "**operationalNoticeMock**" as expected object result (it passes anyways giving a false positive result)

Any help/suggestion ? :)
Thank you!

EDIT: add details for **false positive** test passing

Comment: This code seems to work. Are you sure that you are passing `true` in `toggle` in order to perform the filtering?

Comment: A simple suggestion. Put a `console.log('toggle is true')` inside the `if (toggle)` in order to ensure that is entering. If this is the case and still not working, please share your feedback.

Comment: yes, I debbuged it, it enters the if(toggle)
my issue when I unit test it, the test always passes even when I set the same object  as expected result


https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-test-run-draft-gczdsg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

Comment: Please, update your question providing details about the test you are doing and point out that is test related

Comment: I have provide you an answer with a Fork of your Stackblitz. Hope this hgelp you!

Answer (score 1):

This is as you pointed out due to object mutation issues. As you probably know `Objects` in Javascript are by reference. If you mutate the `Object` a simple comparison wont show you any cahnge, so you have to perform a deep comparison.

**Try the following in your test:**

```js
  it('filterRowOnCosCoeValue should filter operationalCapacities when toggle on', () => {
    const expectedResult = JSON.stringify(operationalNoticeMock);
    const result = JSON.stringify(filterObject(operationalNoticeMock, true));
    expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
  });
```

I have forked the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-test-run-draft-yqunky?file=src/app/app.component.spec.ts)

**EDIT**

Right now the test is failing but if you replace the value with expectedOperationalNoticeMock will pass.

**Change this line:**

```js
const expectedResult = JSON.stringify(operationalNoticeMock);
```

**By this one:**

```js
const expectedResult = JSON.stringify(expectedOperationalNoticeMock);
```

It will pass as expected.